# Introduction to the Conditional Expectation

Tags: probability, expected-value

I'm new to the conditional expectation and wanted to understand the definition of it but I still don't get it..

Consider $X$ a random variable and $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ real-valued. Let $\mathcal{G}$ be a sub-algebra of $\mathcal{F}$.
Show the following things:

- $\mathbb{E}(X | \mathcal{G}) \geq 0$ if $X \geq 0$
- $\mathbb{E}(1 | \mathcal{G}) = 1$
- Consider $Y$ another real-valued variable. Show that $\mathbb{E}(Xg(Y)|Y)=g(Y)\mathbb{E}(X|Y)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Since $X\geq 0$ and by the definition of conditional expectation,

$$E(X|G)=\int^{\infty}_0 x f(x|G) \mathrm{dx}$$

We can see that $x f(x|G)\geq 0$ for all $x\in [0,\infty)$, since $x\geq 0$ and $f(x|G)\geq 0$ by definition. Since the function is nonnegative on the whole interval it's being integrated over, we can deduce that the integral is nonnegative as well.

**2)**  A constant doesn't take on any values with probabilities, since it's not "random", hence why we call random variables random - they take on values with certain probabilities. So the expected value of something that doesn't change is itself.

**3)** In the expression $E(X|Y)$, we integrate over all possible values of $X$, since $Y$ is observed, i.e., we know what value $Y$ is. Now, using this fact, you can deduce that $g(Y)=a$, for some $a\in \mathbb{R}$. Furthermore, $E$ is linear, meaning $$E(aX+bY)=aE(X)+bE(Y)$$

So $E(G(Y)X|Y)=E(aX|Y)=aE(X|Y)=g(Y)E(X|Y)$

If you haven't already, take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23600/intuition-behind-conditional-expectation?rq=1) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/571732/mean-expected-value-or-expectation-of-a-constant) question.

Comment: Thank you so much! This helps a lot!